# Kernel does not support 64 bit cpu

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot, kernel

I installed old Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS (i386) alongside Windows 10 and I get the following error message:

```
error: kernel does not support 64 bit cpu
error: you need to load the kernel first 
press any key to continue ...
```

I need this version to run on hardware (without VirtualBox ~ Virtualization). How to boot 32-bit OS version on 64-bit Hardware? How can I solve this problem?

Note: I have activated the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) in the BIOS configuration. Without that, I am not allowed to install Ubuntu.

Here is cpu info:

```
developer@dev:~/Desktop$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           69
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
Stepping:                        1
CPU MHz:                         1062.315
CPU max MHz:                     3100,0000
CPU min MHz:                     800,0000
BogoMIPS:                        5187.79
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        4 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
```

Comment: Don't install outdated releases and you'll be happy.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL or *end-of-life* thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: I tested Lubuntu & Xubuntu up to the 19.04 releases on boxes/laptops as old as from 2003 (pentium M, pentium 4 & later), plus a lot more up to 18.04 (when most other *flavors* dropped i386). Your cpu lists as newer than many of the boxes I used to test far later releases, so why use such an old release (you're off-topic here due to EOL & ESM status).  An i7 isn't i386 or 32bit restricted.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt use such a old version
If you are worried about your hardware just install xubuntu or lubuntu which i recommend using xubuntu because of its good user interface
Plus i have to mention that i tested xubuntu 20.04 (the latest LTS version) on a 2.7 GHz dualcore cpu with 2 Gb of ram and it works perfectly so you have much better hardware than that old pc you will do good dont worry

Comment: Another option would be 16.04 but it's lifespan is limited.